# Python-Oracle: Process does not write all rows from Oracle table

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, python-oracledb

I'm using a python script to write output from an Oracle table as a .txt file. The Oracle table has around 33,000,000 rows, but when the process finishes, the txt file has around 985,000 rows. Am I missing something in my script that's preventing the process from writing the entire table?

```
import datetime
import arrow
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import os.path
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"xxxxxxx")

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('xxxxxxxxx')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'xxxxx', password='xxxxx',dsn=xxxx)  

i = datetime.datetime.now()
current_date = arrow.now().format('YYYYMMDD')
year = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y')
month = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%B')
directory = "\\\xxxxx\\"+"CY"+year+"\\"+month+year+"\\"


SQL_QUERY = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM CLINICAL_LAB_SUPP ", conn, chunksize=1000000)


file1 = directory + "MyFile_{}".format(current_date) + ".txt"

for df_chunk in SQL_QUERY:
    df = pd.DataFrame(df_chunk)
    df.to_csv("{}".format(file1), index=False, header=True, mode='w+', sep='\t')
```

Comment: Could the mode be the issue? Seems that the file keeps truncating after the first 1,000,000 are written. Does mode = 'a+' make more sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a large number of rows, you may want to use the native driver to remove any overheads of pandas and SQLAlchemy:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import os
import csv
import getpass
import traceback

import oracledb

un = 'cj'
pw = getpass.getpass(f'Enter password for {un}: ')
cs = 'localhost/orclpdb1'

try:
    connection = oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs)

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.arraysize = 1000  # tune this for large queries
        print('Writing to emp.csv')
        f = open('emp.csv', 'w')
        writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
        cursor.execute("""select * from emp""")
        col_names = [row[0] for row in cursor.description]
        writer.writerow(col_names)
        while True:
            rows = cursor.fetchmany()  # extra call at end won't incur extra round-trip
            if not rows:
                break
            writer.writerows(rows)
        f.close()

except oracledb.Error as e:
    error, = e.args
    traceback.print_tb(e.__traceback__)
    print(error.message)
```

Comment: Consider using a context manager on text file to avoid need to close: `with open('emp.csv', 'w') as f:`

Comment: Good idea.  Some of my other tests do that.  In this case I'll leave the change as an exercise for the original poster.